# Is category method overriding a potential security issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, categories

I accidentally managed to create a category method with the same name as a UIKit method. This resulted in UIKit calling my method instead of the library method, resulting in some weird UI glitches. After reading this and prefixing my method, the bug was gone:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1908/_index.html

I was thinking, isn't this a potential security issue? I can essentially decide to overwrite a system method runtime? I did overwrite a harmless UI method, but I could have done the same with security / user authentication classes...

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possibly to use this technique to modify processes if you can write to their memory. A similar approach is how [F-Script Anywhere](https://pmougin.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/the-revenge-of-f-script-anywhere/) works (or did work; I haven't been able to get it working recently).

However, Category extensions exist at the process level, not the system level, so this won't impact other processes and won't allow you to elevate your privileges directly (anything you could do with this, you could otherwise).

You may be imagining a category in your app being executed by Finder when it uses the same object, and that can't happen.

Comment: What is also worth mentioning is that in case of using the same names in categories the behaviour is undefined - either the original implementation will be called or yours. If one really wanted to change one of `UIKit`s methods one would use swizzling.